# Return to search results page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to return to the search results page using jquery, this is my code but always returns to the main data instead of search results data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#kembali").click(function() {
        $("#content").load("../dashB/pesan.php");
        location.hash = "inbox";
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean it always returns main data instead of search results data ? In case you mean you get back unfiltered data I guess its obvious you have a bug in the backend. Furthermore I can not see any param passed in the load function which I think you did not provide

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj ok i will check my backend code again.

Comment: you aren't sending any parameters to the server, so my guess is it probably doesn't know what the user searched for, so it cannot filter the results. Check the docs - http://api.jquery.com/load/ - at the bottom there are examples of how to send data values to the server.

Comment: @ADyson ok i will check

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of returning a filtered data would be like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#kembali").click(function() {
        $("#content").load("../dashB/pesan.php", {term = $('#myTextBox').val()});
        location.hash = "inbox";
    });
});
```

This sample has only one parameter which is called **term**(*but you can modify it as needed*) and then in the backend provide necessary implementation.
If your code is different please provide more info.